# How to remove specific entries from Firebase in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have the following structure in Firebase:
[image: Structure in Firebase]

where the entries contain an `image` and a `timestamp`. The name of each entry is randomly generated and the `timestamp` is an int larger than 0.

**What I want:**

To delete the entries with a `timestamp` smaller than a specific value.

**My current progress:**

I should be able to retrieve the list of sorted entries with the following code:

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://someURL.firebaseio.com/");
Firebase listOfObjects = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("timestamp").getRef();
```

**What's next:**

I want to iterate through and/or somehow only remove specific entries in the `listOfObjects`. Possibly with some if-statements?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I believe you could use `endAt()` to filter just the entries you need

```
Firebase listOfObjects = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(myLimit).getRef();
```

Then something like this should work

```
listOfObjects.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot querySnapshot) {
             queurySnapshot.getRef().removeValue()
        }
}
```